# Cordova InAppBrowser callback is not called

Tags: android, cordova, mobile

In a plain (not Ionic) Cordova project (using webpack for packing and ES6->ES5 transpilation), running on an android 4.4 device, the code below prints *"script is running"* but does not print *"callback is run.."*. I already have checked for a `Promise` return but`executeScript` returns void.

```
    this.browser = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(this.addr, '_blank', 'location=yes');

    this.browser.addEventListener('loadstop', () => {
    this.browser.executeScript({ code: "console.log('script is running'); return window;" }, (result) => {
        console.log('callback is run..');
        this.bwindow = result;
    });
   });
```

Comment: Did you try to apply traditional function style for the callback, instead of arrow function?

Comment: @filipvkovic tried that but nothing changed. Webpack (with babel?) should have handled it anyway....

Comment: be aware that InAppBrowser is another webview, so `console.log('script is running');` will be run on the InAppBrowser webview and `console.log('callback is run..');` in the Cordova webview, if you are inspecting it in chrome, it will appear as two separate windows

Comment: @jcesarmobile checked both, not printed...